# JPA dont save duplicates, point to fields already existing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have two entities `User` and `Sport`. I want JPA to store data about users and list of his favorite sports. Sports table cannot contain duplicates. Whenever I add an user to the database (with favorite sports provided) his data gets saved and if sport he specified exists in the Sports table it gets pointed to the existing row (can be in separate table), if not - new row in sports is created. I tried following with no success:

**sport entity**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long sportId;

    //@Column(unique = true)
    private String sportName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sports")
    private Set<User> users;
```

**user entity**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;

private String username;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Set<Sport> sports;
```

When I save multiple users created like this:

```
User user1 = new UserBuilder("user1").sports(new Sport("basketball"), new Sport("football")).build();
    User user2 = new UserBuilder("user2").sports(new Sport("tennis")).build();
    User user3 = new UserBuilder("user3").sports(new Sport("football")).build();
```

I will get multiple "basketball" and "football" fields in sports table. How to prevent that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are creating new "Sport" object each time rather than reusing the existing objects. Why not just create one "football" etc? That same logic applies to Java objects in general. Nothing JPA specific here .

Comment: The ID is what defines the entities, so if you want there to be only 1 basketball, make the sportName the ID ensuring it is unique.  If your ID is blank, JPA must assume it is new and so insert the object so the sequence can assign a value. But you still should look up existing entities from JPA and use those references rather than create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for a one to many relationship from user to sports.

For that keep the primary key of user as foreign key in sports table.

It will be like

```
   @Id  
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
     @Column(name ="sports_id" )  
     private Long sportId;  
     @Column(name ="sports_name" )  
     private String sportName; 
     @ManyToOne 
     @JoinColumn(name= "user_id")    
     private User user; 


@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy =       GenerationType.AUTO)  
   @Column(name ="user_id" )  
     private Long userId;  
    @Column(name ="user_name" )  
     private String username;     
    @ManyToMany(mappedby="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    Set<Sport>  sports;
```

And to avoid duplicates use primary key of both user and sports while updating the user will be updated and new sports for which primary key is null will be newly added and the existing sports with id will be updated in same row